# How to compare two Items unlocalized names

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

Title sounds like a stupid question at first but this is baffeling me and I couldn't think of a concise way to put it.

Anyways, here is the code I am using:

```
public class OreSword extends ItemSword{

public OreSword(SWORDTYPES sword)
{
    super(sword.getMaterial());
    setUnlocalizedName(RefStrings.MODID + "_" + sword.getName());
    setTextureName(RefStrings.MODID + ":" + sword.getName());
    //setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabCombat);
    sword.setSword(this);
}

public boolean hitEntity(ItemStack sword, EntityLivingBase target, EntityLivingBase self)
{
    System.out.println("this is my override");
    sword.damageItem(1, self);
    if(sword.getUnlocalizedName() == SWORDTYPES.COAL.getSword().getUnlocalizedName())
    {
        System.out.println("this is my sword");
        target.setFire(100);
    }
    return true;
}

public static enum SWORDTYPES
{
    COAL("CoalSword", 1, 131, 4.0F, 1.0F, 5),
    DIAMOND("DiamondSword", 3, 1200, 8.0F, 3.0F, 30),
    EMERALD("EmeraldSword", 3, 2300, 8.0F, 4.0F, 10),
    GOLD("GoldSword", 0, 25, 10.0F, 1.0F, 12),
    IRON("IronSword", 2, 131, 6.0F, 2.0F, 14),
    LAPIS("LapisSword", 1, 131, 4.0F, 1.0F, 44),
    QUARTZ("QuartzSword", 3, 131, 8.0F, 3.0F, 10),
    REDSTONE("RedstoneSword", 2, 131, 6.0F, 2.0F, 14);

    private String name;
    /*private int hLevel;
    private int mUse;
    private float effic;
    private float damage;
    private int ench;*/
    private ToolMaterial mat;
    private OreSword sword;
    private SWORDTYPES(String name, int hLevel, int mUse, float effic, float damage, int ench)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.mat = EnumHelper.addToolMaterial(name, hLevel, mUse, effic, damage, ench);
    }
    public String getName(){return name;}
    public ToolMaterial getMaterial(){return mat;}
    public void setSword(OreSword sword){this.sword = sword;}
    public OreSword getSword(){return sword;}
}
}
```

When I run this code it does output the line "this is my override" but it never prints out the line "this is my sword"

The sword I am testing with in game is the correct sword, I have tested this in creative so the sword doesn't take any damage, and in survival with the sword taking damage.
If someone can explain to me either what I should be doing to check an item or what I might be missing in my implementation I would appreciate it.

Comment: why... are you doing a very expensive string compare on your own objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `public boolean equals(Object obj)` when comparing two strings in Java.

`if(sword.getUnlocalizedName().equals(SWORDTYPES.COAL.getSword().getUnlocalizedName()))`

Also, if they are not equal a nice trick is to try and print them to see what makes them unequal, for example;

`System.out.println("sword: " + sword.getUnlocalizedName());
 System.out.println("SWORDTYPES: " + SWORDTYPES.COAL.getSword().getUnlocalizedName());`

Comment: That worked ... confused as to why it worked though ...
The strings were identical, so why would .equals() work when == doesn't?

Comment: @UberAffe  - `==` does not compare the content of the strings.

Comment: @UberAffe When an object is stored in memory it gets an memory address `0xAAAAA1`. A second object gets `0xAAAAA2`, etc... When you instantiate a string with `"abc def"` java will first look in it's string pool if it's there and use the memory address of that to access the string(look up string pooling). `"abc def" == new String("abc def")` would equate to `0xAAAAA1 == 0xAAAAA2` and that test would fail. They are not the same object. `"abc def" == "abc def"` would pass because its `0xAAAA1 == 0xAAAA1` because it replaced the string creations with the object from the String pool